# Which LiveCD image for USB stick to intall/update GRUB2 on BIOS compatible machine

Tags: uefi, bios

I read a few posts and documents regarding BIOS and UEFI. I am not entirely sure I understood what I needed to do and I need help with bootable USB stick.

A computer previously shipped with Windows 7 also has installed Ubuntu (18.04LTS). I am pretty sure the disk is partitioned using the old MBR and it boots in old BIOS mode, even though the machine is 64bit from 2017 which also supports UEFI. What I need to do is to boot it from USB and run LiveCD, update GRUB2 and hopefully it can boot correctly into Ubuntu or Windows 7.

I am confused about how I should prepare a bootable USB stick with the installer. Do I need to upload ISO image in specific way in advance in order to boot computer from USB in BIOS mode? In other words, for BIOS mode do i need BIOS compatible USB, and for UEFI mode, do I need UEFI compatible USB?

Thanks

Comment: The ISO is configured for both UEFI & BIOS. Some tools like rufus seem to have two options, one UEFI/gpt and one CSM/MBR where CSM is BIOS boot. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. And then in UEFI boot menu with standard installs you get two boot options, one clearly UEFI:flash and one flash (Which is BIOS) where flash is name or label of your USB flash drive. Shows live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wasn't sure I'd have to do anything from my point. I am glad the image is compatible for both modes!

Answer (score 2):

- The current Ubuntu iso files can be **cloned** to a USB drive, and the result is a live drive, that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode.

  The boot mode is controlled by the settings in the computer's UEFI/BIOS system (and independent of the operating system).
- You can use the **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** in your installed Ubuntu (18.04LTS) system for this purpose.

  There are also other tools that can do it (actually all cloning tools), but I think it is most straightforward to use the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have a problem. I tried two Ubuntu LiveCD images: 18.04 and 20.04 cloned to two different USBs using Startup Disk Creator. In both cases, when I tried to boot a computer, there was no option to run them in legacy mode. As a test, I also tried to boot my computer using Fedore 32. That image was cloned using `dd` as SDC does not seem to see the file. Fedora 32, however, has an additional option to boot a machine using legacy mode.

Comment: @Celdor, Please tell us about the computer: brand name and model. Then there is probably someone who knows how to get a temporary menu or enter into the UEFI/BIOS menu system and select which mode to boot into. See also [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB). -- On the other hand, maybe you should continue booting the computer in the same mode that is set to boot. Otherwise you have to switch boot mode when you want to switch between Windows and Ubuntu (when Ubuntu is installed).

Comment: Due to COVID-19, I lost connection to my comp at uni, which is closed. The IT department has not been very keen helping me with that and my degree will end soon. I asked for one-off physical access to repair the computer by myself. It’s only one shot and I need to make sure everything is 100% ready when I get there. I can’t tell more specifications of that computer rather then it is based on ASU’s mobs, intel  Xeon 6 core, 32GB ram. I know it uses MBR and legacy BIOS. Testing images at home , there’s no option to boot my computer in legacy mode using the images I mentioned but I use UEFI.

Comment: At home, I also have ASU’s mono AMD based. I can see booting is set to accept both legacy and uefi modes. I was only testing if images can be run in legacy mode and this is what i was trying to get help with. Thanks for your comment. Perhaps I might need to open a new question if what I provide here is not enough.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that you would like a 64-bit system, that boots only in BIOS mode, so that your computer at home (set  to accept both legacy and uefi modes) will boot in BIOS mode? In that case you can try starting from a template, that uses the 'grub-n-iso' alias 'isoboot' method. This template boots both in UEFI and BIOS mode, but it is easy to disable the UEFI boot mode, simply by deleting the EFI system partition (or at least the content of that partition). See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/isoboot).

Comment: I think it would work with that template in your uni computer (because I have a similar old workstation at home (bought second-hand)). The template comes with MBR (grub-pc bootloader) for BIOS mode (as well as an EFI system partition, that I suggest that you disable). But if you want an MSDOS partition table too, you can try according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy) instead. I'll check that this old method works with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS ...

Comment: This is so complicated. You won't believe it but the ticke is active for a couple of months now. I will have access to that computer just for one day and need to make sure the USB stick works with BIOS/MBR. Currently, I can only test it on my computer at home, which unfortunately in that case is already in UEFI mode. I will try the two links you have provided and see what I can do. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112469/discussion-between-sudodus-and-celdor).